# How to automate adding a framework to "Embedded Binaries"

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

We're building a [Unity](https://unity3d.com/) game for a client that has provided us with an iOS framework. The framework is required to be added as an Embedded Binary. This is simple to do manually, however, we are using [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to automatically make our builds.

[image]

*Note: this is an example image I found on Google.*

**Is there a way to automate this through a script be it with XCode, Unity, or 3rd party tools?**

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer for this question?

Comment: Late reply - I no longer have access to the script but I ended up doing a hardcoded search and replace on the pbxproj file.